# +- knapsack problem

Tags: code-golf, optimization

Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as large as possible.

[Wikipedia for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

For example you can be given a max weight of 15 and objects with value/masses as `[5,2], [7,4] [1,1]` and you would output `[7,0,1]` which is 7 `[5 <value>, 2 <mass>]` objects and 1 `[1 <value>, 1 <mass>]` object for a score of 36.

## Rules

Input can be taken in any reasonable format

Output is also flexible format,

You may not use libraries that are non-standard. If you have to *install* or *download* any library to use it separate from the initial setup then it is ***not*** allowed

Objects may have negative mass and value (i.e -1,-1)

Optimal answers required

## Winning

Shortest code wins

## Negative mass and value?

This is a key part of this challenge. Lets say you have a object with items (mass, value) such as `[4,3],[-1,-1]` and a bag with capacity of 15. You could put 3 of the first ones and score 9 or put 4 of the first ones and one of the -1,-1 object for a score of 11.

Comment: [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/16122#16122)

Comment: Can we assume that no object will have non-positive mass?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino one sec removing for edits

Comment: They may have negative mass and value

Comment: Can we assume everything is an integer?  Also, will we have to deal with cases like [[2, 1], [-1, -1]] where the total value can be made arbitrarily large?

Comment: @Mnemonic all ints, there will be no arbitralily large cases

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156287/73884)

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in the last paragraph: 4*4-1=15, which is more than 13.

Comment: The title is misleading. Due to negative weights this is not the knapsack problem but a variation on the linear programming problem.

Comment: Again in the last paragraph: the score would be 11 (not 15) but the total mass would be 15, above the capacity which is 13.

Comment: @raz opps fixed

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
h.MshMZfghQseMTy*F
```

Outputs as a list of [value, weight] pairs.  Horrendously inefficient, but it *is* NP-complete.
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h.MshMZfghQseMTy%2AF&input=5%2C%20%5B%5B4%2C3%5D%2C%20%5B-1%2C-1%5D%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
h.MshMZfghQseMTy*F
               y*FQ  Get all sets with up to <capacity> of each item.
       fghQseMT      Choose the sets whose total weight fits in the bag.
 .MshMZ              Choose those with the highest value.
h                    Take the first.
```