# Where are my pennies?

Tags: code-golf

Given string `S` representing a dollar amount, make change for that amount of money use the least number of coins to make the change and record the amount of each coin in a list. Here are the coins available to use and their value.

```
Coin : Value
Dollar Coins : $1.00
Quarters: $0.25
Dimes: $0.10
Nickels: $0.05
Pennies: $0.01
```

### Input

String `S` that contains the dollar symbol `$` and the dollar amount.

### Output

List of coin numbers separated by a space character `" "`. The list must be in this order: Dollar coins, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies.

### Constraints

- `$0.00 < S < $10.00`
- `S` is given to two decimal places.
- make change for that amount of money use the least number of coins

### Example Input

`$4.58`

`$9.99`

### Output

`4 2 0 1 3`

`9 3 2 0 4`

### Win Condition

shortest bytes win.

Comment: Do we _have_ to get the `$` sign in the input? I suggest allowing the number itself, either as a number or a string (optional).

Comment: It's essentially the same as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70847/31516), but I personally think it's sufficiently different, since we don't need to output the strings.

Comment: Knapsack problem, possible duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162158/knapsack-problem

Comment: @0x45 I'd upvote this if you remove the `$`-sign requirement in the input, and make the output format optional...

Comment: @StewieGriffin I like the *tricky* part about the `$`, since you have to format the input first. And in the detail the best golfer wins then.

Comment: Fair enough... You might want to read [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/31516).

Comment: I think the input format is interesting but the output being space-separated is just a chore.

Comment: On further thought, this input format isn't interesting either. Because the format is always `$d.dd`, the symbols give no information and so just need to be stripped away or ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [+- knapsack problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162158/knapsack-problem)

Comment: This is OP's question, and the input format as a string is perfectly reasonable for this case.

Comment: @Xcali This is not a duplicate of the knapsack problem, because the list of item sizes is bounded. In fact the only tricky part is how many dimes and nickels to use, and after you divide the input by 5 pennies, this just goes in a cycle mod 5. Knapsack problem requires non-polynomial time. This question can be answered in constant time. This is not an outstanding question but it is not a duplicate of the cited question either.

Comment: What about languages that do not support string input?

Comment: @Xcali Nope, this one can be solved with greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>24</s> 17 bytes

<s>¦'.¡`25‰`10‰`5‰`r5F?' ?}</s>

```
¦'.¡`25‰`T‰`5‰`ðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0DJ1vUMLE4xMHzVsSAgBEWDW4Q2H9/7/r2KiZ2oBAA)

My first attempt at it. It's very verbose in my opinion and I'll look at further revising this answer. Maybe somebody better than me will figure it out.

**Explanation**

```
¦             # Remove '$' from input
'.¡           # Push '.' and split string on that. (dollar),(cents) is result
`25‰          # Push all items onto stack and mod top by 25
`T‰           # Push all items onto stack and mod top by 10
`5‰           # Push all items onto stack and mod top by 5
`r            # Push all items onto stack and reverse stack
ðý            # Loop through stack and print each element with space
```

-7 bytes thanks to Emigna

Comment: Some quick gains: Replace `10` with `T` and `r5F?' ?}` with `ðý`.

Comment: @Emigna How did you go about translating the `r5F?' ?}` to `ðý` if you don't mind so that I can know for future challenges.

Comment: `ðý` means `join by space`, which gives the same result as the `print each with a space after` that you were doing (except with a trailing newline instead of a trailing space)

Comment: @Emigna Oh! I see now. I thought i was some sort of weird encoding, but it is literally push space and b.join(a). I got it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <del>79</del> <del>72</del> 71 bytes

```python
s=input()
d=int(s[1]+s[3:])
for c in(100,25,10,5,1):print d/c,;d-=d/c*c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgFET3/xTyyUJTm6ppoKZ4kpCVWpqNSjSQnt7abmaGx/DSp7xjUNVG5w0i1my2kI5CGbi2Cs2LXC95GeeVwSvuxJItUCkEVxOXgrdgc9rbk7ib5U93Na17W/8MmhH86S35@XtVsbsP0wMBOz1ojV8)

Saved 7 bytes thanks, in part, to [Chas Brown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69880/chas-brown)

Saved a byte thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

Comment: Save 6 via `s=input();d=int(s[1]+s[-2:])`.

Comment: Thanks, I totally overlooked that the input was less than $10, though my previous was flexible. :$

Comment: What's the `~~` for?

Comment: @JoKing The ~ does a [bitwise two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), and two of them reverses it, but essentially performs a [`Math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor) in many languages. And now I realize that the `/` operator does just that in  Python 2 in this case. Thanks for pointing that out! Saved a byte.

Comment: suggest `d%=c` instead of `d-=d/c*c`

Answer (score 5):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <s>35</s> <s>32</s> <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
]{=?2'?!/@[1[5/P0;:!%'[01[5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/z@22tbeSN1eUd8h2jDaVD/AwNpKUVU92gDI@f9fxVLP0hIA)

There are no no-ops `.` now, <s>so it must be optimal</s>.

[image: Colored.]

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19BQSFWoVrBVsGeS0HBSEFdwV5BUUGfS8FBIVrBEIhNgZwABQMFawUroISqgjoXUNAAIvX/v4qlnqUlAA). This way of using "functions" in Hexagony is very interesting

Comment: @JoKing Thanks! (originally I intend to use `$` or `>` and throw it in a loop, but then figure out this way after trying to rotate the program to save some bytes)

Comment: [One more](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19BQSFWoVrBVsGeS0HBSEFdwV5BUUGfSyFawRSIDYHYjitAwUDBWsEKKKGqoM4F5ICETf//V7HUs7QEAA). This one ends in a divide by zero error and prints an excess space though (also, what program are using to create the images? It doesn't look like the one I usually use)

Comment: @JoKing Hexagony Colorer (of course), but I have to remove the caps  (and I was too lazy to reimplement it) because of a [Mono bug](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/7201). (also with some change-font feature...)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 106 bytes

```matlab
@(n)[k=(f=@fix)(x=str2num(n(2:5))),m=f(4*(x-k)),t=f(10*(s=x-k-.25*m)),p=f(20*(s-.1*t)),100*(s-.1*t-.05*p)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PchBCsMgEEDRfc9RcEbqoBKhFgZyj9JFKRVK0IbEBm9vJpvu/vvfV31u756YiPoIBe8TQ@IxfRpC47UuvvwyFPC3gIiXzAkGDc1MgipwVsPKYkM@6Cx3luuPa8jpKsPZvwzZoGd89ATqPFC4KjwdGSlGhX0H)

16 bytes is used simply to get rid of `$` and convert the string to a number. The rest is simply removing the as many coins as possible, one value at a time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ä┐¢6ⁿ≡♠₧ç7╦Δ╛XÄR│
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=84bf9b36fcf0069e8737cbffbe588e52b3&i=%244.58%0A%249.99&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 81 bytes

```r
x=as.double(substr(scan(,""),2,6));for(i in 1/c(1,4,10,20,100))x=x-i*print(x%/%i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRbCoAgEADAq0gU7MZmGhZBeBjtAQthoQXe3pqPiaVk65LcrtefO6TXpydCWl0AqiqkgSbE5bgisOAgdL@CJkNa0aD@FWK2ueP2jhweyE3fMJbayHEuHw)

26 bytes ensuring the data are a `double` rather than a string, very nearly a third of the program! That's lame, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 74 bytes

```ruby
->s{n=s.delete("$.").to_i;["%s"]*5*" "%[n/100,n/25%4,(m=n/5%5)/2,m%2,n%5]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczdCoMgGIDhW4mPhAqnTvpqMtyNiIyNFQjpYtbBqF17@/Po5Tl5H/P1ufV6253iEnRkt27opq6AnEHJpvvZHQ2QCLbCCjIgJvC9EDRwiaSmhdeBI8GSS@qJpIGgfW3jPMXMQF4zFEB/xX@b5Ca5TW6T8fCtYkqBZf4yLqtbe@M@zzc)

Converts input to an integer containing number of pennies, then applies formulas in the `[]` at the end.

```ruby
5 bytes standard Ruby boilerplate ->s{}
34 bytes on solving the problem
35 bytes on formatting
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```
!s=(x=parse(Int,filter(>('.'),s));[100,25,10,5,1].|>u->(t=x÷u;x%=u;t))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ldBLCsIwEADQfU9R_wmMIakVLCXFnXiG2kWgqUREJR_owpu46cYzCG49hbextX5WLmTCDOSFITOn88Ztlaju11xYwVPP97urfkimsy5P0hACoMBgkkELEYmiBiKYPCl8AyWUNUChDfYF9gH2gszr-fXpGI5KfhDaSLTcWSjU1kqNlMnVWlkwGMcpoxSCKTAKdcrIMXHjBFle3i4uLgfcxRbjs7PFeHZf_OiXoBEZ4b_bDYu99pEBLQ3mzXLqeebCGKlt83Ne33tyl7evq6qtDw)

- -1 byte: `x=x%u` -> `x*=u` - thanks to @MarcMush

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 138 bytes

```java
s->{long p=new Long(s.replaceAll("\\D","")),c,i=100;for(s="";i>0;s+=c+" ",i=i>25?25:i>10?10:i>5?5:i>1?1:0)for(c=0;p>=i;p-=i)c++;return s;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hU/BTsMwDL3vK6yIQ6q2UVpWiS5KKySOsAtHxiFkGcrI0ihJh9DUby8Z9AySLT/bz9Z7R3EW5XH/MUsjQoAnoe1lBaBtVP4gpILttQV4jl7bd5B4ASFjaT6lTBGiiFrCFixwmEPZXcyQOI5b9QmPCeJAvHIm/bs3BqPd7gEVCGVZIQvNK0rZYfA4cISY7igLOZc5ApR2uqubvm42uqtoX9FUm/6n66sNza5XklPmOq6ZK7nOZJ4zr@LoLQQ2zexXnxvfTNK3yDwPeg@nZHTx8vIqssXkV4jqRIYxEpc20VhsicToZk2auySX/c1qSdv@z6rqW7JuFt60muZv)

```java
s->{              // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  long p=new Long(s.replaceAll("\\D","")),
                  //  Remove all non-digits, and convert it to a number
       c,         //  Count-integer
       i=100;     //  Amount integer, starting at 100
  for(s="";       //  Set the input to an empty String, because we no longer need it
      i>0         //  Loop as long as `i` is not 0
      ;           //    After every iteration:
       s+=c+" ",  //     Append the count and a space to `s`
       i=i>25?    //     If `i` is 100:
          25      //      Change it to 25
         :i>10?   //     Else-if `i` is 25:
          10      //      Change it to 10
         :i>5?    //     Else-if `i` is 10:
          5       //      Change it to 5
         :i>1?    //     Else-if `i` is 5:
          1       //      Change it to 1
         :        //     Else (`i` is 1)
          0)      //      Change it to 0
    for(c=0;      //   Reset the count `c` to 0
        p>=i;     //   Inner loop as long as `p` is larger than or equal to `i`
        p-=i)     //     After every iteration: subtract `i` from `p`
      c++;        //    Increase the count `c` by 1
  return s;}      //  Return the result
```